# PHP - comparing 2 identical strings returns false

Tags: php, php-curl

I have read some posts about this problem. Tried to use `trim` but it does not help.

Php script sends a `curl` request to another server which returns `ok` if the request were successful.

```
$request = curl_send_function($uid, "suspend");
if ($request != 'ok') {
echo $request;
exit;
}
```

The script shows `ok` and stops to excecute - exits. Why `ok` is not `ok` for the script?

`var_dump($request);` shows the following:

```
okstring(0) ""
```

Comment: `okstring(0) ""` is an empty string.

Comment: Your curl request __outputs__ result, not returns it. Use `RETURN_TRANSFER` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "ok" isn't saved in `$request` but printed by your `curl_send_function`. You need to set the cURL option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```